# Set component attribute but don't fire event

Tags: events, websocket, polymer

I'm new to polymer/webcomponents and I'm trying to set an attribute in a component but **don't want the corresponding event to be fired**.

**Why?** Because I want to be able to do two things:

**1)** When the control changes (by clicking on the checkbox) I want to use the event handler to send this event to a server (using websockets)

**2)** When the control *should* change (by an event via websocket) I want to be able to set the checkbox but not fire the event.

Hope I made my point clear. It's very hot in germany right now -> brain is melting ;)

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">

<polymer-element name="webmpc-player">
  <template>
    <paper-checkbox id="repeat" on-change={{change}}></paper-checkbox>&nbsp;Repeat
    &nbsp;
    <paper-checkbox id="shuffle" on-change={{change}}></paper-checkbox>&nbsp;Shuffle
  </template>
<script>
  Polymer('webmpc-player', {
    ready : function() {
       /* Set the component property */
       this.$.shuffle.checked = true;
    },

    change : function(e, detail, sender) {
       alert('I don't want to be called!');
    }
  });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this looks like a flaw in `paper-checkbox`.

I just posted an issue ticket to describe the problem.

https://github.com/Polymer/paper-checkbox/issues/9.

Comment: In the meantime you may be able to work around it by listening for the `paper-radio-button-activate` (checkbox is an extension of radio-button) event instead of `change`.

Comment: Woohoo ... first time ever found a real bug in a peace of software while I'm **not** at work ;) - Thank you!